# symfony2 submit selected request fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

In certain cases, I want to update just two fields of the entire form to the database even if the user has changed all other fields.

```
$form = $this->createForm('user', $user);
$form->submit($request);
if($certain_conditions){
 // update only the "favourites collection" and don't entertain other user changes.?
}
$em->flush();
```

What are the possible ways of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution.

```
$form = $this->createForm('user', $user);
if($certain_conditions){
    foreach($form as $k=>$v){
        if($k != 'favourites') $form->remove($k);
    }
}
$form->submit($request);
$em->flush();
```